# opendir functions uses which systemcall

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, readdir, opendir

As i see opendir(*******)/readdir(*****) is a function coming from library. We get information from  "man 3 opendir" . man 3 is for c functions. man 2 is for systemcalls.

In linux every thing is  a file. A normal file can be opened from "open" system-call which return  file descriptor (or) we we can use function "fopen" function which returns FILE pointer . "fopen" internamlly uses "open system-call
Same like this "opendir/readdir" return DIR pointer, I want to know "opendir/readdir" uses which systemcall   internally.

Comment: Check the related man pages, the glibc source code, or the output of `strace` ran with a dummy program that just does `opendir`.

Comment: It uses open(2) and getdents(2) internally